How to get the distributive law for an l-group?
In Birkhoff an l-group G is defined as a group that is also a poset and in which group translation is isotone:
\begin{gather*}
x\leq y\implies a+x+b\leq a+y+b\;\forall a,x,y,b\in G,
\end{gather*}
and in which any two elements have a glb and lub. Such G apparently satisfies
\begin{gather*}
a+(x\vee y)=(a+x)\vee(a+y)
\end{gather*}
and though I see $(a+x)\vee(a+y)\leq a+(x\vee y)$ I don't know how to get the reverse inclusion from the definition above.

Let us single out the inequality you already established:
\begin{equation}
\label{dist-ineq}
(a + x) \vee (a + y) \leq a + (x \vee y)\tag{$\star$}
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{align}
x \vee y
&= (-a) + a + (x \vee y)\\
&\geq (-a) + ((a + x) \vee (a + y)) \tag{$\because\star$}\\
&\geq ((-a) + a + x) \vee ((-a) + a + y) \tag{$\because\star$}\\
&= x \vee y.
\end{align}
This implies that all inequalities above are, indeed, equalities;
in particular,
$$(-a) + a + (x \vee y) = (-a) + ((a + x) \vee (a + y)),$$
or, summing $a$,
$$a + (x \vee y) = (a + x) \vee (a + y).$$
